# Running httpd as different user?

Tags: php, apache, permissions, httpd.conf

I am running httpd on aws ec2 instance on Amazon Linux 2.

For installing LAMP stack I used [this link.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html) The instance is running perfectly.

I need to execute a shell command from php using `shell_exec('sh somescript')`. The script then intern creates a folder using `sudo mkdir foldername`. This folder never gets created.
So, I directly write `shell_exec('sudo mkdir foldername')`. Doesn't work.

I tried `shell_exec('whoami')`. This outputs `apache`(because of the group I had created from the installation.)

Other things I tried :

- Changing permission and ownership of the folder and subfolder of the directory. (Didn't work).
- Changing the user & group in `httpd.conf`.(Give Error 503, if I use ec2-user and doesn't start if I use root, which btw the comments asks.)

My question :

1. Why am I not able to create folder from php when httpd is running as apache user/group, when ec2-user is a user of the apache group?
2. Is it safe to use httpd with ec2-user as the user and group? If so how? If not what is the alternate?

Comment: In the php-fpm.conf file you can set a user and group for php (user=ec2-user and group=ec2-user). Also be sure to chown the appropriate folders to at the very least your new group. (chown user:group /path). You may also need to set +rw for group using chmod.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this on my own.
For future reference, all I did was restart the instance and all the services.

I did not had to change the user or group for httpd. Although I'm still not sure if it is safe to do, but I was able to get around without it.